React Query invalidateQueries not working in my NextJS 14 application
I'm using the react query in my application but the invalidateQueries not working.
This is the acceptFriendshipRequest :

const useAcceptFriendshipRequest = () => {
    return useMutation({
        mutationKey: ['accept-friendship-request'],
        mutationFn: async ({requesterId}: { requesterId: string }) => await acceptFriendshipRequest({requesterId}),
        retry: 1,
    })
}
export default useAcceptFriendshipRequest;


The setQueryData works correctly but the invalidateQueries to get the profile by id not working, there is no get profile by id in the network :

 await queryClient.invalidateQueries({
                    queryKey: ['get-profile-by-id', user.requester_id]
                });


This is the getProfileById function and the query key is totally correct but the fetch not happening :

export const useGetProfileById = (id: string) => {

    return useQuery({
        queryKey: ["get-profile-by-id", id],
        queryFn: async () => await getProfileData(id),
        enabled: !!id,
        retry: 1,
        refetchOnMount: false,
        refetchInterval: false
    })

};



From your code, there are two things I think should be checked
1.) Be sure that enabled: !!id, resolves to true,
2.) Use variables for your query keys. Consider doing this instead:


//Define query keys
const queryKeys = {
  profileById: (id: string) => ['get-profile-by-id', id]
};


export const useGetProfileById = (id: string) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: queryKeys.profileById(id),
    queryFn: async () => await getProfileData(id),
    enabled: !!id, // Be sure this resolves to true
    retry: 1,
    refetchOnMount: false,
    refetchInterval: false,
  });
};


//To Invalidate
await queryClient.invalidateQueries({
  queryKey: profileById(user.requester_id),
});



